# how can bring to front clicked div in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bringtofront

I want bring to front div which is clicked , how can do that?

Here i added some divs in HTML:

```
<div class="div1">A</div>
<div class="div2">B</div>
<div class="div3">C</div>
```

i set size of div in here with CSS Code:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #666;
    border-color: #333;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:50px;
}
.div1 {
    left: 91px;
    top: 66px;
}
.div2 {
    left: 132px;
    top: 152px;
}
.div3 {
    left: 171px;
    top: 90px;
}
```

also in here i want change the active div when div is clicked, it should bring to front when is clicked, how can do that with Jquery:

```
$(".div1").click(function() {
    // make div 1 front of the screen
})
$(".div2").click(function() {
    // make div 2 front of the screen
})
$(".div3").click(function() {
    // make div 3 front of the screen
})
```

Comment: :D everybody wrote true codes i don't know what answer i should accept

Comment: Accept the one that's most flexible and doesn't mess up pre-existing z-index settings ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify a `z-index` property for each of the three divs, say `1`, in your CSS. Then upon your click, increase the `z-index` of the div that was clicked.

```
$('div[class^="div"]').click(function(){
    $(this).css('z-index', 2);
    //reset other sibling div's z-index to default value (i.e. 1)
    $(this).siblings('div').css('z-index', 1);
});
```

*Note that here I'm assuming all of you three divs are in the **same container** div.*

Comment: Thanks @Ahmad Baktash Hayeri, Many thanks to everybody

Answer (score 3):

Create a class called `front` and style it as such:

```
.front{ z-index:100; }
```

Then add/remove this class as necessary:

```
$('.front-on-click').click(function(){
    $('.front').removeClass('front');
    $(this).addClass('front');
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmrqwrwb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".div1,.div2,.div3").click(function(){
    //assign all divs `z-index` = 90 including clicked one
    $(".div1,.div2,.div3").css("z-index","90");

    //assign `z-index` = 100 to clicked one
    $(this).css("z-index","100"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index to the div and when click change the z-index value of others

**Snippet:**

```js
$(".div1").click(function() {
    $('div[class^="div"]').css('z-index', '0');
    $(this).css('z-index', '10');
})
$(".div2").click(function() {
    // make div 2 front of the screen
  $('div[class^="div"]').css('z-index', '0');
  $(this).css('z-index', '10');
})
$(".div3").click(function() {
    // make div 3 front of the screen
  $('div[class^="div"]').css('z-index', '0');
  $(this).css('z-index', '10');
})
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #666;
    border-color: #333;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:50px;
}
.div1 {
    left: 91px;
    top: 66px;
}
.div2 {
    left: 132px;
    top: 152px;
}
.div3 {
    left: 171px;
    top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">A</div>
<div class="div2">B</div>
<div class="div3">C</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with z-index for positioned elements.

```
$('.div1, .div2, .div3').click(function(){   
    $('div').css('zIndex',2);
    $(this).css('zIndex',200);    
});
```

Its better if its possible to limit the zIndex reset of all divs here. To do that add a seperate class for divs.

```
.focusable{
    position:absolute;
}

<div class="div1 focusable">A</div> 
<div class="div2 focusable">B</div>
<div class="div3 focusable">C</div>

$('.focusable').click(function(){   
    $('.focusable').css('zIndex',2);
    $(this).css('zIndex',200);    
});
```

Example in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L87ar9ax/ .